# how to get mysql connection error log in lambda, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql2

I wonder difference to main, function

environment
nodejs  14.x
mysql2 2.2.3

I made code,

call pool.getconnection in main, it's fine(success data from db)
but can't get a data from function.

I wonder why this can't get from function

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: SERVICE_INFO.DB_HOST,
  database: SERVICE_INFO.DB_NAME,
  user: SERVICE_INFO.DB_USERNAME,
  password: SERVICE_INFO.DB_PASSWORD,
  port: SERVICE_INFO.DB_PORT,
  connectionLimit: 20,
})

async function getData() {
  try {
    const connection = await pool.getConnection(async conn => conn) // error why??
    await connection.query(~~~)
  } catch (error) {
   
  }

}
module.exports.main = async (event) => {
 const connection = await pool.getConnection(async conn => conn);
 const result = await connection.query(`~~~`);
 connection.release()

}
```

can't find error log only find Promise pending..
Promise {  }

Comment: Sharing the error would help

Comment: sorry, can't find error log in aws cloud watch

Comment: Then how do you know that line is the one that threw the error? Couldn't it be the query on the line after?

Comment: in fact, function has more code but connection fail, not show  console.log. and I think connection query can't load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`getConnection`](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/3a250e51d20507be3293bbdeedbcb50811d23a3e/lib/pool.js#L37) method does not return a `Promise`, you should be able to retrieve the connection in the callback:

```
function getData() {
  pool.getConnection(async (err, conn) => {
    try {
      if (err) throw 'Something went wrong';
      await conn.query('<query>');
      pool.releaseConnection(conn);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

You can find an example in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).